# Condition checking in two complex multi-dimensional arrays of same shape

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 10x2x2 complex64 arrays. I want to find which of the 2x2 arrays are not all zero in one or both:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.zeros((10,2,2), "complex64")
b = numpy.ones((10,2,2), "complex64")

empty_one_or_both = (a.reshape(10,4) != 0).all(axis=1) * (b.reshape(10,4) != 0).all(axis=1) # EDIT
```

The goal is to perform other operations only on non-empty pairs, like:

```
numpy.sqrt(a[empty_one_or_both])
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Using `*` will only match those with both matrices zero.  I think you want `|`.

Comment: See edit, looking for reverse problem, finding which are not all zero in both, as to have a usable mask.

Comment: In that case, I'd definitely prefer `&` or `numpy.logical_and()` over `*`.  The result is, of course, the same, but multiplying Boolean values when what you want to express is a logical AND seems a bit weird.  (Apart from this, I can't think of anything you  might want to improve about this approach.  It is straight-forward and efficient, so what bothers you?)

Comment: I thought there might have been a way to do it without reshaping.

Comment: Of course you could do `(a == 0).all(1).all(1)`, because you want to use .`all()` along two axes.  I don't think this is any better than what you have (and neither any worse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of numpy 1.7 you can do:

```
a.all(axis=(1, 2)) & b.all(axis=(1, 2))
```

See the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all) for more more info, but if you're using an older version, I think you have to reshape, or do all(1).all(1).

Comment: Accepting this, but thanks to Sven Marnach for his comments, too.